# Change to Bootstrap default Col min-width affects responsive design

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

After upgrading from Bootstrap 4.4 to 4.5 I noticed cards within columns which used to respond responsively when the screen size is made smaller, now become stacked (i.e. overlap).

It appears to be related to a CSS change in 4.5 where the col min-width defaults to 0.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30049

Effect can be viewed in this example by simply changing the CSS bootstrap setting between 4.4.1 (responsive) and 4.5 (stacked)
https://codepen.io/alonergan/pen/BaoGqwO

Would like to ask if anyone else noticed this, and if it is an intended consequence or a regression in bootstrap 4.5?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like a correct behavior so what is it you want cards to happen on decrease in screen size ?

Comment: The example used bootstrap 4.4, which behaved correctly. I modified the example to use 4.5, to illustrate the new behavior whereby the cards are overlapping.

Comment: overlapping? mean one card top of another? I don't see that behavior all I see is on decrease of screen size it wraps and makes it as single column

Comment: May I suggest you refresh the page and re-run the snippet, just to confirm the changes I made in the example from BS 4.4 to 4.5 are in effect?

Comment: I can see it now, remove the `width:18rem;` and make to `width:100%;` from 3 cards. you can use `flex` to make it clean too.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the input. I found a preferable solution for my code is to add/overwrite the col min-width with, for example, min-width: 18rem (or indeed stick with the older BS version).

Comment: Glad it worked! cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex items have a minimum width equal to their content, In other words a flex item cannot be smaller than the content it's holding. Something like `min-width:content` if you will. ***(The same is true for the height)***

**Bootstrap 4.4** recognizes that constraint, However **Bootstrap 4.5** overrides it with `min-width:0` on `.col`

---

The solution is simple, We explicitly say that we want to respect the content

```
.col { min-width:auto !important; }
```

```css
.col{
  min-width:auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: I only looked in the code to recognize the difference, I'm not aware if bootstrap did mention this or not.*

Answer (score 0):

You can now also upgrade to Bootstrap 4.5.1 to fix this problem.
Issue https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30999 has been fixed.
Full changelog: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.5.1